# Get single object term for custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to get the custom taxonomy term for a single custom post type and seem to be falling flat. I thought the most obvious answer was to use `single_term_title()` but have tried just about every term related Wordpress function I could find in the codex but most of them seem to return arrays and I only want the term title for `single-match.php` Here is what I thought would work.

```
<?php $matchtype = single_term_title("", false); ?>

<h5><?php echo  $matchtype->slug . ' match' ?></h5>
```

Comment: I assume that `single-match.php` means that you are on a single view of your custom post type. Are you sure that WordPress runs a custom taxonomy query on this page? Could you run a `var_dump( get_queried_object() );`?

Comment: Yes, single-match.php is a single view or the custom post type. You're right it doesn't look look like. Nothing resembling post category or post taxonomy. I suppose I should do a custom query then and then presumably I'll be able to use `single_term_title()` ?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. If you have a single match (your CPT) and you want to display the type of match to which it is associated (your custom taxonomy), then you could use `get_the_terms()`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms The first code example should work.